To what extent can a widespread false conspiracy theory make a case for a lawsuit?
One story has been that Stanley Kubrick directed the video of the Moon landing and made it fake, but that seems like it is defamatory to Stanley Kubrick and to the staff at NASA who did real work.
Assume that person A works as a subcontractor for NASA, and does not accept statements that he is part of a conspiracy like Moon landing or Mars landing being faked or similar.
Similar questions have been around here e.g.
criminalise Moon landing deniers
But in my jurisdiction it is irrelevant if the claim is true or false.
The law over here (but other jurisdictions are also interesting for the answer)

Chapter 5 – On defamation Section 1 A person who identifies someone as
being a criminal or as having a reprehensible way of life, or
otherwise provides information liable to expose that person to the
contempt of others is guilty of defamation and is sentenced to a fine.
If they were obliged to make a statement or if, in view of the
circumstances, it was otherwise justifiable to provide information
about the matter, and if they show that the information was true or
that they had reasonable grounds for it, they are not held
responsible.
Section 2 If an offence referred to in Section 1 is gross, the person
is guilty of gross defamation and is sentenced to a fine or
imprisonment for at most two years. When assessing whether the offence
is gross, particular consideration is given to whether the information
was, in view of its content or the method or scope of its
dissemination or for some other reason, liable to result in serious
damage. Act 2017:1136.
Section 3 A person who, in cases other than those referred to in
Section 1 or 2, directs accusation, a derogatory statement or
humiliating conduct at another person is, if the act is liable to
violate the other person’s selfesteem or dignity, guilty of insulting
behaviour and is sentenced to a fine. If the offence is gross, the
sentence is a fine or imprisonment for at most six months.
Section 4 Defamation of a deceased person results in responsibility
under Section 1 or 2 if the act is offensive to the person’s survivors
or if, considering the time that has passed since the deceased was
alive and the other circumstances, the act can otherwise be deemed to
disturb the peace to which the deceased should be entitled.


The law over here - which law, and over where?

@littleadv it seems to me that this might be from sweden...

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

@littleadv The law is not the answer to a question about what would constitute a case. The practice of the ruling court is not like a deterministic machine that just applies a law. In my jurisdiction, the practice cannot be deduced from simply reading the law. One must look at real cases how the court rules, and the jurisdictions can be many in this case, the project can be international so it is misleading to zoom in to a specific jurisdiction.

@NiklasRosencrantz My point was that if you quote something - provide a reference. You quoted something, but you didn't provide any reference to where the quote came from. it is misleading to zoom in to a specific jurisdiction - when it comes to freedom of speech, it is not something you can generalize. In some countries saying something that's verifiably true may land you in jail, and in others saying something verifiably false may be a protected speech.

Freedom of speech depends on the jurisdiction.
How much Freedom of speech you have depends ONLY on the jurisdiction you are in.
In the united-states that is very wide stretched and only limited by Fighting Words, imminent lawless action and defamation. In other countries, the lines are very much different. For example, germany allows to sue for insults and damages to the honor.
But there's also totally different category of statements that are illegal by laws in different countries. For example, the denial of the Holocaust or a similar act that attacks a wide swath of the population are at times defined as crimes in multiple countries all over Europe. Similarly, specific ideologies are banned, and mimicking their paroles is a crime.
Some conspiracy theories are illegal to voice, such as claiming the holocaust wasn't real in germany
Denial of the Holocaust is one of the many shapes of Volksverhetzung in Germany, illegal as a crime under StGB § 130. But that is not a sueable offense, it is a prosecutable one.
Parroting some ideologies is criminal, such as "Wiederbetätigung" in austria
Austria has a law banning the NSDAP or similar organisation, as well as all attempts to reconstitute it or a similar organisation - the Verbotsgesetz

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
